# Compare cells based on dropdown

Tags: microsoft-excel, comparison

I have multiple products, each with various features. I would like to choose a product from a dropdown list and then populate its features below, then do the same for a second product next to it.

My product table looks something like this:

[image]

And I have something like this in mind for the dropdowns:

[image]

What formula can I use to populate the features of each of the products to compare? I tried using `SUMIF` but to no avail.

Comment: Have a try using [INDEX MATCH functions](http://www.contextures.com/xlFunctions03.html) and tell us if you are still stuck

Comment: @JMax Please post an answer as this was exactly what I was looking for.

Comment: Glad it helped you :). I've posted it as an answer but feel free to edit it or to add your own answer as described [here](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/17463/can-i-answer-my-own-questions-even-those-where-i-knew-the-answer-before-asking)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Even if this is not a full working answer, as discussed in the comments, the right way to hande this is to use a combination of [INDEX and MATCH functions](http://www.contextures.com/xlFunctions03.html) as described in the given link.

Please feel free to edit this answer (even if you have not the rights yet, it will get approved by mods) with the answer you found by yourself.

Answer (score 1):

An **HLOOKUP** should do the trick. In **I3** you would have something like this:

```
=HLOOKUP(I2,A1:E3,2,0)
```

And in **I4**:

```
=HLOOKUP(I2,A1:E3,3,0)
```

An HLOOKUP is an "horizontal lookup", the not-as-common little brother of VLOOKUP. It picks up your lookup value (Model1), scans the first row of your table (A1:E3) and returns the value in the second row (2). The zero on the end ensures that the text you are searching for is matched exactly (I assume you are referencing real text names and not actually "Model1").